# Wake the Android Screen after a timer fires

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, timer

How can I have a timer fire a method to wake up the screen of an Android device?

I inserted this:

```
final Window win = getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); 
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

into the

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

method.

Additionally, I made a timer after a user clicks a button which runs the following program:

```
final int interval = 3000; // 3 Seconds
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
      public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            };
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

I want to be able to click the power button of my Android device to sleep it within the 3 second interval and have it wake up after the run() gets fired.
What do I call to trigger the screen to turn on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method also instantly turns on the screen:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock TempWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TempWakeLock");
TempWakeLock.acquire();
TempWakeLock.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add to onCreate() :

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```

To release the screen lock:

```
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
        KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
        keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Add to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Comment: Thanks, after implementing this, I tried running a timer and releasing the screen lock and it worked! But what steps do I take to wake up the screen? (I turn off the screen right before the timer fires)